# Compare two columns of two different dataframes with different shapes in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two different dataframes with the same column title and I would like to compare the columns content and remove the values that are present in data frame A but not present in data frame B, for instance,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('1', 'A',    389.0, 1.2),
           ('2', 'B',     24.0, 1.4),
           ('3',   'C',   80.5, 2.2),
           ('4', 'D', 13.4, 5)],
           columns=['items', 'Chambers', 'V','I'],
           )
df2 = pd.DataFrame([('1', 'A',    389.0, 1),
           ('2', 'E',     24.0, 2.1),
           ('3',   'C',   90.5,1.8),
           ('4', 'B', 10, 0.7),
           ('5','D',80.5,7)],
           columns=['items', 'Chambers', 'V','I'],
           )
```

I would like to erase the values "D" and "E" in df2 and preserve all others. I hope this is clear :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You say you want to remove the values that are present in dataframe A but not in dataframe B. You then say that you would like to erase the value "E", but that value isn't present in dataframe A. Please may you clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Chambers = B is the same situation as Chambers = D, so its hard to understand exactly what you are looking to do.  In situations where you want to get only the rows from one DataFrame that are in another merge is an option.  merge creates a combined DataFrame with correlated data between the two DataFrames.

For example:

```
df2.merge(df1, how='inner', left_on=['items', 'Chambers'], right_on=['items', 'Chambers'])
```

gives you a combined DataFrame where both 'items' and 'Chambers' match between df1 and df2.

```
  items Chambers    V_x  I_x    V_y  I_y
0     1        A  389.0  1.0  389.0  1.2
1     3        C   90.5  1.8   80.5  2.2
```

Or if you wanted just the rows where Chambers matches:

```
df2.merge(df1, how='inner', left_on=['Chambers'], right_on=['Chambers'])
```

gives:

```
  items_x Chambers    V_x  I_x items_y    V_y  I_y
0       1        A  389.0  1.0       1  389.0  1.2
1       3        C   90.5  1.8       3   80.5  2.2
2       4        B   10.0  0.7       2   24.0  1.4
3       5        D   80.5  7.0       4   13.4  5.0
```

If thats not exactly what you mean can you provide an example of your expected result?